# Problem in GWT realex integration while registering new card

Tags: gwt, payment-gateway, realex-payments-api

In my application I am using realex to pay amount.While doing that I registered new user with realex but after that when I tried to add new card then I am getting response from realex that Sha1 hash incorrect.I checked sha1 hash structure it is all right but still I am getting this error.If anyone know this so please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

may be you missing any dot in your SHA1 Generation method

Chk it.

Answer (score 0):

You were trying to process a card-new transaction I believe? The correct fields to use in the sha1hash are

```
timestamp.merchantid.orderid.amount.currency.payerref.chname.cardnumber
```

In a card-new request, amount and currency will be blank, so you will create a string by concatenating the other values joined with dots, e.g.

```
20130312105733.yourclientid.yourorderid...yourpayerref.cardholdername.4242424242424242
```

Get the sha1hash of this (make sure you convert the resulting hash to lower case hex letters! This is vital so that the next step is performed the same way Realex do it)

```
fc63ee950d69f275a0d54927072e4d675133ccfd
```

(Not: FC63EE950D69F275A0D54927072E4D675133CCFD - your SHA1 library may produce upper case hashes - you must convert to lowercase.)

Then add a dot and your secret and hash again.

```
fc63ee950d69f275a0d54927072e4d675133ccfd.yoursecret
```

To get:

```
112bf11fae62dc3116800b4a00457206dc2f1308
```

Again, make sure you convert to lowercase hex letters like I have.

Owen

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you pass the right data as perameters.. I'm currently using below method and it works fine on my site..

$today_timestamp :- Current timestamp
  $merchant_id :- your merchantID
  $order_id: make sure you are passing the right order id and validated using the rules provided in the developer documentation.. 
  $amount :- Current Price. This has to be full digit. ex: if a user wants to pay $4 then it has to be 400.. 
$currency:- ths is GBP in my case..

```
$sha1hash = $today_timestamp . "." . $merchant_id . "." . $order_id . "." .  $amount . "." .  $currency   ;
    $sha1hashed_string = sha1($sha1hash);
    $string_with_shared_secret = $sha1hashed_string . "." .   $shared_secret;

    $sha1hash_string = sha1($string_with_shared_secret);
```